# With htaccess, I would like to replace a bad url Query String parameter with a correct one, or correctly formatted one

Tags: .htaccess

I have a url: "domain.com/category-b&utm_source=x%20yz" I'd like to fix the formatting so that the first ampersand with "&utm_source" uses the proper query string format with a question mark like: "?utm_source"

This worked(thanks arkascha)for resolving the very precise issue of the "&" replacement with a "?"
RewriteRule ^/?([^&]+)&(.*)$ /$1?$2 [R=301,L,QSA]

However, encoded characters in the rewrite cause a 404

Does Not Work" "&utm_source=I%20AM%20Google"
Does Work: "&utm_source=IAMGoogle"

*I applied a workaround and more rules, but the answer was posted and accepted, as it answered the original question I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual rule is pretty straight forward. You just capture the parts before and behind the first ampersand in the requested URL and reassemble things afterwards:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([^&]+)&(.*)$ /$1?$2 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

It is important however to note that this only fixes a symptom, not the cause. This is a way to solve old URLs still stored somewhere out of your reach (like on google). This is *not* a propper way to get around fixing the URLs getting created and handed out. That is something you have to fix in your application logic.

---

UPDATE:

In the comment below you ask how to handle url encoded characters correctly...

Strictly speaking a URL like `https://example.com/category-b&utm_source=xyz&utm_source=I AM Google` is formally invalid. A blank character is *not* valid inside a URL. Maybe you just refer to what you enter into the browser's address bar, including blank characters, in that case the browser will internally encode them as %20 to request a valid URL. You can play around with the flags `NE`, `B` and `BNP` (see the documentation for their exact meaning) to modify the exact result. Most likely you just want to add the `B` flag here, but that is hard to tell because it is completely unclear what you mean by "broken".

Comment: Thank you. This is similar to what I tried and didn't have quite right. This resolved what I thought was the major issue. However, any HTML encoded characters later in the URL break on redirect, and only on the redirect. Is there some sort of declaration for escaped characters to preserve or fix in this rewrite rule I need to add to preserve or fix character encoding?

Comment: I added an update to the question. I cannot be more precise, since your question is value.

Comment: I resolved the issue with a modification to the rewrite you provided.  I have later parts of the URL that are HTML encoded, and when completely removed the rewrite would work.  I ultimately just decided to strip all the parameters passed as they weren't needed.

Comment: OK, since you did not explain what you actually mean by "broken" there is nothing more I can add. Just a short note: there is no such thing as "HTML encoded". I _assume_ you refer to a _url encoded_ string inside a URL.